# Remove the newline from asctime()

Tags: c++, newline

I want to get rid of the new line that `asctime()` gives me after the time

```
string str;
time_t tt;
struct tm * ti;
time(&tt);
ti = localtime(&tt);
str = asctime(ti);
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    cout << str;
```

the output is

```
fri apr 26 00:59:07 2019
fri apr 26 00:59:07 2019
```

but i want it in this form

```
fri apr 26 00:59:07 2019fri apr 26 00:59:07 2019
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since the newline is the final character, all you have to do is remove the final character in the string. You can do this by calling `pop_back`

```
str.pop_back();
```

On Windows, a newline is `\r\n` **BUT** `\n` is the platform independent newline character for C and C++. This means that when you write `\n` to stdout in text mode the character will be converted to `\r\n`. You can just use `\n` everywhere and your code will be cross platform.

Comment: Wouldn't `\r` be in there too on Windows?

Comment: @NikosC. Oh right Windows. Two characters are better than one apparently. I'll figure something out

Comment: Probably check in a loop if the last character of the string is either `\n` or `\r` and if yes, pop it.

Comment: I think Windows should only add `\n` as its the official `C++` line terminator (files are converted to and from it on reading and writing to maintain internal consistency).

Comment: @Galik Could be. Not sure. My Windows-foo is a bit rusty.

Comment: So far, Visual Studio Code, and Code::Blocks both have only `\n`. What other compilers could be used on windows?

Comment: could somebody try this on Windows: `std::cout << int (std::endl) << '\n'`?

Comment: @NikosC. no, it's the job of the C++ runtime to convert the system new line character to `'\n'`, just like on classic Mac you print `'\n'` and it'll be converted to `'\r`' in the output

Comment: @0x476f72616e what are you trying to achieve with that? `std::endl` is a function returning reference to std::basic_ostream, not some numeric value that you can print. And even if you want to know the new line character, that doesn't work because in C and C++ the new line is always `'\n'` regardless of the system new line (like classic Mac's `'\r'`)

Answer (score 2):

Removing the last characters of the string as per Kerndog73's answer will work, but since you're using C++, you have a better solution available: The [std::put_time()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time) stream manipulator:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

// ...

auto tt = time(nullptr);
auto* ti = localtime(&tt);
std::stringstream sstream;
sstream << std::put_time(ti, "%c");
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    cout << sstream.str();
```

If you don't need to store the time as a string, you can just print it out directly:

```
auto tt = time(nullptr);
auto* ti = localtime(&tt);
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    cout << std::put_time(ti, "%c");
```

Answer (score -1):

While you can use `pop_back()` in a loop, with C++11 and later, you are left to check the final character before removal to ensure you are trimming a line-ending and not a wanted character. You can make use of the `.c_str()` member function and the `strcspn` function provided by the `<cstring>` and the `reject` sting containing both `"\r\n"` to automate the process. Here, `strcspn` returns the number of characters not containing either of the characters.

You can use the number of characters not including the line endings to pass to the member function `.erase()` to remove all characters beginning from the first included line-ending, e.g.

```
    str.erase (strcspn (str.c_str(), "\r\n"));
```

You can simply copy that number of characters to a charter bufffer, e.g.

```
    char trimmed[64] {};   // sufficiently sized to hold the asctime() return

    str.copy (trimmed, strcspn (str.c_str(), "\r\n"));
```

Using `.erase()` your first example would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main (void) {
    time_t tt; 
    struct tm *ti; 
    time(&tt);
    ti = localtime(&tt);
    std::string str (asctime(ti));

    str.erase (strcspn (str.c_str(), "\r\n"));
    std::cout << "str: '" << str << "'\n\nor your output\n\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        std::cout << str;
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Using `.copy()` you could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main (void) {
    time_t tt; 
    struct tm *ti; 
    time(&tt);
    ti = localtime(&tt);
    std::string str (asctime(ti));
    char trimmed[64] {};

    str.copy (trimmed, strcspn (str.c_str(), "\r\n"));
    std::cout << "str: '" << trimmed << "'\n\nor your output\n\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        std::cout << trimmed;
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

The output is the same in both cases, e.g.

```
$ ./bin/asctimetrim
str: 'Thu Apr 25 21:24:43 2019'

or your output

Thu Apr 25 21:24:43 2019Thu Apr 25 21:24:43 2019
```

Both handy additional ways to trim the line endings provided by `strcspn()` to add to your C++ toolbox.

Comment: Uhhh nope, please explain.... What that usually means is you have been @jww'ed. One of the most petulant. Not uncommon if he doesn't like the question, he then downvotes every answer. (kinda reminds of the tantrums my children had when then were toddlers -- there in college now, so there is proof people can grow out of such problems) If you notice - he edited the question...