# How to format a chrono::time_point as a string

Tags: c++, time, c++-chrono

I need to get current date and time in c++. I can use `chrono` to get the `system time` but I also need to save this in json file as string. Moreover the chrono time which I have tried gives below format:

```
auto time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
```

output:

```
Thu Oct 11 19:10:24 2012
```

But I need date time format in below format:

```
2016-12-07T00:52:07
```

Also I need this date time in string so that I can save it in Json file. Can anyone please suggest a good way to achieve this. Thanks.

Comment: Use `stringstream` to format it however you like

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55858985/856199). Use `"%FT%T"` as format string instead of `"%c"`. Unless you need to compare dates and time intervals, you don't need to use `std::chrono`.

Comment: UTC, local time zone, or some specific non-local time zone?

Comment: @HowardHinnant UTC

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use [Howard Hinnant's free, open-source, header-only date.h](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/include/date/date.h):

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto time = system_clock::now();
    std::string s = format("%FT%T", floor<seconds>(time));
    std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

This library is the prototype for the new C++20, chrono extensions.  Though in C++20, the details of the formatting may change slightly to bring it in line with the expected C++20 `fmt` library.

### C++20 version

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <format>
#include <string>

int
main()
{
    auto time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::string s = std::format("{:%FT%T}",
                       std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::seconds>(time));
    std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

[Demo.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XdNPuC5pYASfqTE1)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>

std::string getTimeStr(){
    std::time_t now =     std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(std::chrono::system_clock::now());

    std::string s(30, '\0');
    std::strftime(&s[0], s.size(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", std::localtime(&now));
    return s;
}
int main(){

    std::cout<<getTimeStr()<<std::endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You do realize that is not UTC?